# Duplicate build condition name: "always" Jenkins job dsl

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a declarative pipeline, where I need to get a build notification plus use a plugin for another set of action, no matter the build result. So I am using the post section with always [conditional](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post-conditions).  But writing the always conditional twice gives me the below error.

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:

WorkflowScript: 72: Duplicate build condition name: "always" @ line 72, column 5.

       post {
```

The post sections looks like below

```
post {
    always {

          step([$class: 'GitHubIssueNotifier',
               issueAppend: true])
    }  
     always {
      emailext ( 
         .
     .
     .

         )
     }
```

How can I run two actions in a single post conditional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was finally able to figure out how to do, multiple actions can be performed in a single always conditional.

```
post {
    always {

          step([$class: 'GitHubIssueNotifier',
               issueAppend: true])

          emailext ( 
                .
                .
                .
                    )
     }
 }
```